# Datepicker stops working after jquery load

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, load

I am using datepicker with jquery ui with input

```
<input type="text" name="first_day" id="datepicker-first_day" class="input-text" />
```

and the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker-first_day").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a page that loads and then when a link is clicked it loads the page with the following:

```
function load_page() {
    $('#load-page').load('pages/annual-leave/annual-leave', 'show=all');
}
```

The date picker works the first time the page is loaded but after calling the load_page function it stops working.

I have confirmed that jquery ui is loaded both times.

I have tried the following through answers on stack overflow

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker-first_day").live("click", function () { $(this).datepicker(); });
});
```

(this one doesn't even work the first time)

I have also tried other similar things to the .live like .on etc.

Nothing I try seems to work?

Has anyone had a similar problem or know why this may be happening?

I have searched all day through google and stack overflow for an answer but can't fix it.

Edit: It is also worth noting that when the page is initially loaded it also uses the load_page function.

Comment: Does the page you load contain an element with the same ID? What errors do you get in the console? Also, why are you escaping the quotes in `dateFormat: \'dd/mm/yy\'`?

Comment: No the ID is unique, I don't get any errors in the console and sorry I should have changed that it's because the script is within php tags.

Comment: Does your "#datepicker-first_day is inside #load-page element?

Comment: Hi, yes it is. The header and sidemenu always remain the same and all content is loaded within the #load-page element (including the datepicker).